# type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage returning expression from expression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to return an expression from a Select, so I have an expression returning an expression (I think - maybe it's a lambda returning an expression, I'm not sure of the terminology)

If I create a variable that explicitly gives a type to the expression then it works e.g.

```
housingDivisions.Select(id => {
    Expression<Func<Document, bool>> expression = d => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id);
    return expression;
})
```

however this code seems equivalent (and less wordy)

```
housingDivisions.Select(id => d => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id))
```

but causes a compile error:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Is there any way of getting this to compile without having to create an unnecessary variable?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the type arguments to `Select` explicitly? If you need to do this frequently, you could add your own extension method (`SelectExpression` or something like that) which would probably help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried

    housingDivisions.Select(id => (Document d) => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id))

but I got the same error

Comment: That's specifying the parameter type for the lambda expression. I was suggesting specifying the type arguments, as per Rhaokiel's answer. However, it would be good to know if this is something you do in lots of places. If it is, do you always return an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` or might the return type of the function be different?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using this in a bunch of places, so a `SelectExpression` extension method would be a good idea but I haven't figured out how to do that yet

Comment: Okay, I can write up an answer with that. And do the lambda expressions always return bool? (Could you tell us the types of `housingDivisions`, `Document.HousingDivisions` and `HousingDivisionId` please?)

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah they'll always return `bool` because they're used in a Where to build a query.  `housingDivisions` is a `List<int>` (a list of the Ids of housing divisions we're filtering the query on), `Document.HousingDivisions` is a `List<HousingDivisionDocument>` (the collection of join entities on Document, because it's a many-many reference), and `HousingDivisionId` is an `int` (the Id of the HousingDivision from the join entity).  Really the details of what the expression does aren't that important, I just need to turn a list of ids into a enumerable of expressions that filter on each id

Comment: There is a standardized way of doing a select many-many reference using LINQ, would it make more sense to just do that? I was running under the assumption that you needed an Expression tree object which is used for stepping through dynamic code, not so much for running dynamic code. `from id in housingDivisions
 from doc in Document.HousingDivisions
 where doc.HousingDivisionId = id
 select doc`

Comment: @Rhaokiel the reason I need expressions is because I'm combining them with OR instead of AND, which I can't do by just chaining .Where together

Comment: Okie-Dokie... I've update my answer with the requested extension method to Select Expression

Answer (score 1):

The problem is both the type `d` and the delegate type of `d => ...` are both unknown and cannot be assumed from anywhere. You can solve both in one go by instantiating the delegate type:

```
housingDivisions.Select(id => new Func<Document, bool>(d => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id)))
```

If you absolutely need the type to be an Expression tree, then you can convert to it by casting:

```
housingDivisions.Select(id => (Expression<Func<Document, bool>>)(d => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id)))
```

The compiler suggests explicitly specifying the arguments. Personally I think that way is a little bit more wordy. But it would look like this:

```
housingDivisions.Select<int, Expression<Func<Document, bool>>>(id => d => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id));
```

---

Here's an extension method for Selecting an Expression:

```
public static IEnumerable<Expression<Func<ExprArg, Result>>> SelectExpr<TSource, ExprArg, Result>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, ExprArg, Result> func)
{
    return source.Select((o) => (Expression<Func<ExprArg, Result>>)((arg) => func(o, arg)));
}


// Use:
housingDivisions.SelectExpr((int id, Document d) => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id));
```

Comment: The second option is nice, but ideally it would be even less wordy - that's a long typename to have all over the place in the code

Comment: The problem with the extension method is that the expression is just calling the function so EF doesn't translate that into SQL and I get `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'where Invoke(__func_0, __o_1, [d])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'.`

Comment: You're heading down the road to convoluted... Here's what you'd have to do to supply the parameter to already built expression and reduce it so that LINQ can translate to SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960103/reduce-an-expression-by-inputting-a-parameter

Comment: I honestly think you'd be better off finding a way to work with LINQ rather than circumvent it.

Comment: Otherwise there is no simpler way than the cast that I put above. You can't build an extension method that can assume the parameters of the Expression inside of a Func like you want. I tried. Unless you hardcode the types.

Comment: Yeah an ExpressionVisitor is what I'm using.  I'm working with LINQ as much as I can, but when you're building a dynamic query and you want WHERE x AND (y1 OR y2) when you don't know how many y's there are going to be, I couldn't find any other way of doing it.  If it's not possible to do an extension method to make it look cleaner then I'll live with it the way it is

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how all of your data is laid out and which ones are local vs remote. But I've achieved WHERE x AND (y1 OR y2 OR...) by using something similar to this: `Documents.Where((d) => d.X && d.HousingDivisions.Any((h) => housingDivisions.Contains(h.HousingDivisionId)))` where housingDivisions is a local List<int> and the rest are DB entries

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot - that works.  I thought it wouldn't because I've had `QueryClientEvaluationWarning` errors when trying to filter on local `List<int>`s.  I think the difference is that I had them the other way around `.Where(d => housingDivisions.Any(id => d.HousingDivisions.Any(h => h.HousingDivisionId == id)))`

Comment: Yeah somewhere I read that the only extension method that will translate for local collections is `Contains` so I set the order of the logic up to take advantage of that.